# Creation of a map of pointer to member function

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

I am trying to create a map composed of `int` and pointer to member function.

```
class Factory
{
  public:
    typedef nts::IComponent *(*createFunction)(const std::string &value);
    Factory();
    ~Factory();
    nts::IComponent *createComponent(const std::string &type, const std::string &value);
  private:
    nts::IComponent *create4001(const std::string &value) const;
    nts::IComponent *create4013(const std::string &value) const;
    nts::IComponent *create4040(const std::string &value) const;
    nts::IComponent *create4081(const std::string &value) const;

    std::map<int, createFunction> map = {{4001, Factory::create4001},
                                        {4013, Factory::create4013},
                                        {4040, Factory::create4040}};
};
```

But I have this following error:

```
includes/Factory.hpp:24:68: error: could not convert ‘{{4001, ((Factory*)this)->Factory::create4001}, {4013, ((Factory*)this)->Factory::create4013}, {4040, ((Factory*)this)->Factory::create4040}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<int, nts::IComponent* (*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>’
                                         {4040, Factory::create4040}};
```

Have any idea?

Comment: Read up on the topic in your favorite book before using it. `createFunction` is not an alias for a member function pointer. It also lacks a `const` qualifier.

Comment: Try `using createFunction = nts::IComponent * (const std::string&);`, and then use `std::map<int, createFunction Factory::*> map;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Same error

Comment: @DimitriDanilov: Sorry, I forgot the `const` and the address-of. [Demo](https://ideone.com/YWJg5S).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef` for a pointer to (non-static) member function looks like this:

```
typedef nts::IComponent *(Factory::*createFunction)(const std::string &value) const;
//                        ^^^^^^^                                             ^^^^^
//                  nested name specifier                             missing const
```

Preferable form:

```
using createFunction = nts::IComponent *(Factory::*)(const std::string &value) const;
```

Initialization of your map:

```
std::map<int, createFunction> map = {{4001, &Factory::create4001},
                                     {4013, &Factory::create4013},
                                     {4040, &Factory::create4040}};
//                                          ^
//                      compiler would think you're trying to call
//                      a static function without an argument list
```

Comment: FWIW, the mechanism to retrieve and execute the function from the map is by:

     std::map<int,createFunction>::iterator result = func_map.find( 4001 );
     createFunction *method = result->second;
     (obj.*method)( value );